# Problema al sobreescribir en un archivo .txt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vscode, consola

Estoy teniendo problemas para que StreamWriter no sobrescriba un archivo .txt. Como puedo hacer para que no sobrescriba o machaque el archivo?

```cs
while (num % div != 0 && div <= Math.Sqrt(num))
{
    div++;
}

if (div > Math.Sqrt(num))
{
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Alumno\\source\\repos\\calculadora_numeros_primos\\logprimos.txt";
    string texto = ($"|{num}|");

    using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
    writer.WriteLine(texto);
}

div = 2;
num++; }
```

Comment: Buenas, Aitor, bienvenido al sitio. No tengo mucha idea de C# y no se entiende muy bien cuando exactamente no quieres que sobreescriba. ¿No quieres que sobreescriba nunca o no quieres que sobreescriba mientras dure tu programa? En cualquier caso, de acuerdo con [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7306236/2553194), creo que solo necesitas añadir un argumento más cuando creas el StreamWriter: true.

Comment: Hola, perdón si no me he explicado. No quiero que se sobrescriba mientras el programa este ejecutándose. El output que espero es los números unos detrás de otros: 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | ...

Comment: Ya lo he probado y funciona, gracias.

Comment: De nada, pero deberías sacar la instanciación del StreamWriter del bucle, no necesitas crearlo en cada iteración. Basta con que lo crees una vez. Con eso creo que te bastaría sin añadir el true. Con el true puede que se te acumulen varias ejecuciones del programa y obtengas esa lista repetida.

Comment: @RubioRic no esta en un bucle... pero seguro esta en una funcion que llama varias veces, pero por lo menos en lo que muestra, no esta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [este constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)) con el segundo parámetro en `true` para que agregue el contenido al final del archivo:

```
new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

Para un control más fino, [este otro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-io-filestreamoptions)) que recibe un objeto de configuración.

```
var opciones = new FileStreamOptions {
  Access = FileAccess.Write,
  Mode = FileMode.CreateNew
};
new StreamWriter(path, opciones);
```

O bien comprobar si el archivo existe con [`File.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists#system-io-file-exists(system-string))